# Linux tc (traffic control) tool - problebs with ssh connection after configuration

Tags: linux, shell, network-programming, network-traffic

I have a simple goal : to emulate 'bad traffic' between 2 vm-s A(server) and B(client).

My script at node B(client):

```
 tc qdisc del dev eth4 root
tc qdisc add dev eth4 root handle 1: prio
tc qdisc add dev eth4 parent 1:1 handle 2: netem delay 300ms 300ms loss 10%
tc filter add dev eth4 parent 1:0 protocol ip pref 55 handle ::55 u32 match ip dport 4800 dst 172.29.49.115 flowid 1:1
tc filter add dev eth4 parent 1:0 protocol ip pref 55 handle ::55 u32 match ip src 172.29.49.115 flowid 1:1
```

That works fine, but the issue that I'm experiencing - the emulation impacts my connection with node B [ C(my machine) - B(client)] via ssh. When I set package loss up to 60%, that's almost impossible to go further...

How can I avoid that?

btw, filters seem to work fine, pingi google.com from B works fine, ping A from B - with package loss and delay. Pinging B from C(my machine) - either without delays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The band for the high priority traffic (guaranteed maximum speed and priority 1)

```
tc qdisc add dev eth3 parent 1:5 handle 50:0 sfq perturb 1
```

ssh on the strip with a high priority

```
tc filter add dev eth3 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 0 u32 match ip sport 22 0xffff flowid 1:5
```